# Does google restrict more than one sites on same server with identical design or content?

Tags: seo

I have two websites [url removed] and [url removed] with resembling content hosted on same server.
Google pick only one of them. Is this a criteria of google to pick only one website from one server for identical content?

Answer (score 1):

Google is doing their best to filter out duplicate content from their search results as it is low quality content and not what people a looking for. No matter where you host your sites this is going to happen. See [the Panda Algortithm](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Panda) for more about this.